# Unexpected result of java calculations

Tags: java

As a result of the following snipet, i got "1 0 1", but i don't know why, im expecting "1  1  1" as a result. please can anyone explain to me how things go arround

```
public class Qcb90 {
int a;
int b;
public void f() {
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    int[] c = { 0 };
    g(b, c);
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c[0] + " ");
}
public void g(int b, int[] c) {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c[0] = 1;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Qcb90 obj = new Qcb90();
    obj.f();
}
}
```

Comment: the `b` in `g` is its function parameter, the `b` in `f` is the member. use `this.b` in `g` to assign to the member.

Comment: this.a = 1;
this.b = 1;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
b = 1;
```

to

```
this.b = 1;
```

The way you have it now, you are changing the parameter (local) variable not the class member variable.

Comment: And by *local variable* you mean *parameter*.

Comment: Updated to clarify.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `int` is not a reference object, for example it is not the object which is created by the word `new`, so inside the method when you pass b to the method, a new variable will be created for this, and it can just be valid in this method. If an Object that is created by the word `new`, then it will got affect if it changed by any other method.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter named `b` in function `g(int b, int[] c)` *hides* the class member variable `b`, so you are setting a local parameter called `b` to 1 in `g(int b, int[] c)`.  This doesn't affect the member variable at all, and the new value is discarded after `g` exits.

However, the local parameter `c` is a copy of the *pointer* to the memory that was allocated in `f`, so you can modify the contents memory since both copies of the pointer (the copy passed in as a parameter to `g` and also the original in `f`) point to the same block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Qcb90 {
    int a;
    int b;
    public void f() {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        int[] c = { 0 };
        g(b, c);
    // so here b is your instance variable
        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c[0] + " ");
    }
    public void g(int b, int[] c) {
        a = 1;
        //b = 1;  this b is a parameter of your method 
this.b=1; //now run your program


        c[0] = 1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Qcb90 obj = new Qcb90();
        obj.f();
    }
    }
```

If you want to print `b` value you need to write `this.b` inside `g()`

Comment: i would like to vote you up, but im not permitted to do so, im a novice here.
i need to earn more reputation score to do so. sorry dude